# Custom functions to alter entity

Tags: php, symfony

In the Symfony2 project, I want to write some custom functions to change some setters and getters in an Entity class. At first, using [service container](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/service_container.html) come to my mind. If so, how can I include and use the service inside the entity class? Or is there any convenient way to do it?

Comment: Maybe I am misunderstanding, but why don't you just add the custom functions to the entity class?

Comment: I just want to use these functions (which are not specific to any entity) globally.

Answer (score 0):

From a controller:

```
MyBundle::container = $this->getContainer();
```

From an entity

```
$container = MyBundle::$container;
```

But don't do this.  Pretty much violates every core Doctrine principle. In the D2 universe, entities should only know about other entities.

Consider posting a description of one of the custom functions you need and perhaps someone can help.